# What is the proper way to use google line charts with dates

Tags: charts, date

I see [this link to use google chart api](http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/gallery/linechart.html) for putting multiple line charts together

What is the recommended way to have dates on the bottom line as it seems like each row in the chart has the same level of space so if i have charts where their are dates and values i want the correct spacing to be there between date values (1 day difference should be different than 1 month apart data points).

It seems like of you put dates in the first column it keep every "row" the same distance apart horizontally.

**EDIT**: I have added my code below

---

```
function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Target');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Actual');

        data.addRows(9);

        data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(2010, 1, 1));
        data.setValue(0, 1, 215);
        data.setValue(0, 2, 215);

        data.setValue(1, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 1));
        data.setValue(1, 2, 213);

        data.setValue(2, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 4));
        data.setValue(2, 2, 213);

        data.setValue(3, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 8));
        data.setValue(3, 2, 213);


        data.setValue(4, 0, new Date(2010, 3, 1));
        data.setValue(4, 2, 220);

        data.setValue(5, 0, new Date(2010, 4, 1));
        data.setValue(5, 2, 190);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That example uses a string to store the year, so no "smart" spacing will occur. However, the Google `DataTable` does support `Date` and `DateTime` column types, so that should suffice for your needs.

http://code.google.com/apis/visualization/documentation/reference.html#DataTable

Basically, instead of calling

```
...
data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
...
```

You would do

```
...
data.addColumn('date', 'TheDate'); // or datetime, depending on your needs
```

---

**Edit:** in that case, you probably need to pad the date values yourself. It looks like the fixed spacing comes from the row index in the DataTable. For instance, you can see that this code generates differently-spaced data points in the chart:

```js
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Target');

  data.addRows(9);

  data.setValue(0, 0, new Date(2010, 1, 1));
  data.setValue(0, 1, 213);

  data.setValue(3, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 1));
  data.setValue(3, 1, 213);

  data.setValue(4, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 4));
  data.setValue(4, 1, 213);

  data.setValue(5, 0, new Date(2010, 2, 8));
  data.setValue(5, 1, 213);

  new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).draw(data, null);
}
```

Comment: this helps but doesn't solve the issue.  I have now change it to dates but the horizontal space between two points is still identical even if its a day apart or a year apart

Comment: @Bears will eat you - thanks for your reply.. since i will have all types of dates, using different row indexes seems a bit insane. i think i may switch to using flot grid instead.

Comment: Well, depending on your date range vs. density in that range, the following may or may not be feasible for generating correctly padded data: given a Date d, to generate d's index in your DataTable, just use the difference (in days) between d and your earliest date as the row index into the DataTable.

Comment: @Bears will eat you - with flot you dont have to do any of this, it just works out of the box.

Comment: Then it sounds like Flot is the better hammer for this nail.